# Show that $u(x,y)$ is a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am studying complex analysis, and have ran into some trouble. I saw this sample problem:

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ an entire function such that $u(x,y)\leq K$ for all points in the complex plane. Show that $u(x,y)$ where $a$ is a constant function.

As I saw, the solution goes as follows:

We take the function $h(z)=e^{f(z)}$. That function is entire, as it is made of two entire functions. Also, $|h(z)|=|e^{f(z)}|=|e^{u(x,y+iv(x,y)}|=e^{u(x,y)}\leq e^K$

So far I understand what is going on, since all I did was exponentiate the function and use some properties. However, now comes the tricky part for me:

We have to apply Liouville's Theorem, obtaining that
$h(z)=e^{f(z)}$ is a constant function. Then, $|h(z)|=e^{u(x,y)}=K $, and thus $u(x,y)=constant$

But I don't understand that last part. I know that Liouvilles theorem is: $$|f'(z)|\leq \frac{M}{r}$$

But I don't know how it can be applied here to show that $u(x,y)$ is constant.

Comment: You are actually looking for a proof of Liouville's theorem, I guess.. Because it directly implies that your f(z) is constants, and thus the fact that u(x,y) is constant follows trivially. Check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: If you know that $|f'(z)|\leq \frac{M}{r}$ just let $r \to \infty$ which makes  $|f'(z)|=0$ hence $f'=0$ hence $f$ constant